Excel VBA Dictionary Not Filling Corectly
I need to find the number of occurrences in a column where criteria in three other columns (same row) are met. There are also a lot of duplicates I need to exclude.  This is why I am using a dictionary. All of the passed ranges (columns) are the same length, vary up 30,000 rows, and exclude the header.  The Filters I am passing are the criteria and are supplied when calling the function. There are two sheets - sheet and pSheet. I am expecting a result from the function, but it constantly returns nothing.  There should be multiple items in the dictionary.

Hopefully, I have supplied enough information so someone can point out my mistake.  Thanks in advance!
Setting the ranges:
Set columnH = Worksheets(sheet).Range("H2:H" & lastRow)     'Department Column
Set columnI = Worksheets(sheet).Range("I2:I" & lastRow)     'Item # Column
Set columnK = Worksheets(sheet).Range("K2:K" & lastRow)     'CS or PK Column
Set columnU = Worksheets(sheet).Range("U2:U" & lastRow)     'UPC Exists Column

Calling the function:
Sheets(pSheet).Range("T4") = ListLength(columnI, columnK, columnH, columnU, "PK-1", "DRY", "Yes") 'Searches for Items that are PK, in DRY department, and have a UPC

The function:
Function ListLength(Range1, Range2, Range3, Range4, Filter1, Filter2, Filter3) As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim itemList As Scripting.Dictionary
Set itemList = New Scripting.Dictionary

i = 0

For Each Item In Range1
    If Range2(i) = Filter1 Then
        If Range3(i) = Filter2 Then
            If Range4(i) = Filter3 Then
                If Not itemList.Exists(Item) Then
                    itemList.Add Item.Value, 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next Item
                
ListLength = itemList.Count
            
End Function


Range2(0) is not valid  - start i at 1 maybe

I tried that - still returns nothing, not even 0 to the call.

I would give your Range1-4 parameters a type (As Range), and don't test If Not itemList.Exists(Item) Then but use If Not itemList.Exists(Item.Value) Then - dictionary keys can be of any type, including object references, so you need to be explicit exactly what key you want to use.

When adding "As Range" in Function declaration, I get ByRef argument type mismatch.

Function ListLength(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range, Range4 As Range, Filter1, Filter2, Filter3) As Long

I found the problem...obvious and blatant oversight!
I forgot to declare Item as Range!

I got your code working following the changes outlined in my comments, but this slightly different approach is more flexible and easier to call I think:
Option Explicit

Sub tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    
    lastRow = 13 'for example
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Debug.Print CountUniques(ws.Range("I2:I" & lastRow), "K", "PK-1", "H", "DRY", "U", "Yes")

End Sub

' `ValuesRange` contains the values for which you want the unique count
' `Filters` is an alternating list of column indexes (numeric or letter) and values to test for
Function CountUniques(ValuesRange As Range, ParamArray Filters()) As Long
    Dim c As Range, v, itemList As Scripting.Dictionary, rw As Range, i As Long
    
    Set itemList = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    For Each c In ValuesRange.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Set rw = c.EntireRow
            For i = 0 To UBound(Filters) Step 2 'loop over Filters (if any provided)
                If rw.Columns(Filters(i)) <> Filters(i + 1) Then GoTo skip
            Next i
            If Not itemList.Exists(v) Then itemList.Add v, 0
        End If 'value to check
skip:
    Next c
    CountUniques = itemList.count
End Function


you could use AutoFilter() method and then loop through filtered cells only
Function ListLength(dataRange As Range, filter1 As String, filter2 As String, filter3 As String) As Long

    With dataRange

        .AutoFilter 4, "PK-1"
        .AutoFilter 1, "DRY"
        .AutoFilter 14, "Yes"

        Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
            Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

            Dim c As Range
                For Each c In .Columns(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    d(c.Value2) = 1
                Next
                
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

        ListLength = d.Count
            
End Function

as you can see you can pass the entire range instead of splitting it into those 4 sub ranges
and the calling could be like:
Sub main()
    With Worksheets(sheet)
        With .Range("H1:U" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
            Worksheets(pSheet).Range("T4").Value = ListLength(.Cells, "PK-1", "DRY", "Yes")
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Or you can also use the RemoveDuplicates() method and avoid the Dictionary object
Function ListLength2(dataRange As Range, filter1 As String, filter2 As String, filter3 As String) As Long

    With dataRange
        
        Dim vals As Variant
            vals = .Value 'save the range values since some of them will be possibily deleted after RemoveDuplicate() method
            
        .AutoFilter 4, "PK-1"
        .AutoFilter 1, "DRY"
        .AutoFilter 14, "Yes"
        
        .RemoveDuplicates Array(2), xlYes
                
        ListLength2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(2)) - 1 ' count remaining values in column 2 of the range, header excluded
        
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        .Value = vals ' put range original values back

    End With
            
End Function

